# return back the double value with 2 decimals place in Java program

Tags: java

How can i return back the double value with 2 decimals place in Java program?

```
public String toString() 
    { 
      return  "\nCost: $" +computeRentalCost() ;
    }
```

Comment: If you are using a `double` you're SOL; it cannot be reliably "truncated" to two decimals. For this you'd need a `BigDecimal`.

Comment: Recommend you to read this thread regarding accuracy of double/float for currency http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `String.format()`:

```
return String.format("\nCost: $%.2f", computeRentalCost());
```

The format modifier `%.2f` tells that only two decimal places will be shown.

**Note:**

- This won't modify the number, it only modifies the way it's shown.